Metamask transaction error
getting MetaMask - RPC Error: Function object could not be cloned. DOMException: Function object could not be cloned. after signing the transaction
This is how i am signing the transaction
 this.connection = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(_provider);

    const multiSendTx = await this.connection.send("eth_sendTransaction", [
            ...txns,
          ]);


Ensure that txns contains only plain objects without functions or circular references.
